# How to replace only certain record in kdb?

Tags: kdb

I am trying to replace two values in a column in a table. But some records do not have both values. The whole column type is string.

This is the code I have, the column look like:

```
a:([]extraData:("xxx=xxxx;bbbb=bbbb;client=xxxx;Account=oooo;ffaijo=efaie";"xxx=xxxx;bbbb=bbbb;Account=oooo;ffaijo=efaie";"xxx=xxxx;bbbb=bbbb;client=xxxx;ffaijo=efaie";"xxx=xxxx;bbbb=bbbb;ffaijo=efaie"))


update {";"sv @[s;where (s:";"vs x) like "client=*";:;enlist""]}each extraData from (update {";"sv @[s;where (s:";"vs x) like "Account=*";:;enlist""]}each extraData from a)
```

a is the table.  Some records do not have client or account and the code breaks. I am trying to use condition like

```
$["*client*" in a`extraData;;]
```

but do not work.

So my goal is to delete those two values. If just one, delete that one if both delete both.

Comment: Can you provide more info? Like an input table and an expected output? Does each string record look like your same, or is that string used to populate your column?

Comment: Hi Conor, The table has many column. and the column I am trying to replace is called extraData. The whole column is string. It has many values separated by semicolon. I am trying to replace two values. one is account and the other is client. If just one I would like to replace one,two i would like to replace two. none then don't replace. What I am doing now will always try to find it and replace. it breaks when one record does not have one value. Thanks

Comment: it gives me length error when one value is missing.

Comment: Still unsure of what your data looks like, but maybe you could use the parse-kv functionality of 0: to create a dictionary of each string. You can then reference the dictionary, returning nulls when out of bounds, instead of having to build any large if statement. HTH. 
     http://code.kx.com/q/ref/filenumbers/#parse-kv

Comment: the data looks like this "xxx=xxxx;bbbb=bbbb;client=xxxx;Account=oooo;ffaijo=efaie"

Answer (score 4):

I would start by writing a pair of functions to convert your strings to mappings and back:

```
ms:(!)."S=;"0:
sm:{";"sv"="sv/:flip(string key x;value x)}
```

On your data, it works like this:

```
q)ms "xxx=xxxx;bbbb=bbbb;client=xxxx;Account=oooo;ffaijo=efaie"
xxx    | "xxxx"
bbbb   | "bbbb"
client | "xxxx"
Account| "oooo"
ffaijo | "efaie"
q)sm ms "xxx=xxxx;bbbb=bbbb;client=xxxx;Account=oooo;ffaijo=efaie"
"xxx=xxxx;bbbb=bbbb;client=xxxx;Account=oooo;ffaijo=efaie"
```

Now, with

```
a:([]extraData:enlist "xxx=xxxx;bbbb=bbbb;client=xxxx;Account=oooo;ffaijo=efaie")
```

you can do the update as follows:

```
q)update sm each upsert[;`client`Account!("yyyy";"pppp")] each ms each extraData from a
extraData
----------------------------------------------------------
"xxx=xxxx;bbbb=bbbb;client=yyyy;Account=pppp;ffaijo=efaie"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add an if statement in to check if the necessary key exists (probably a nicer solution out there):

```
q)tab:([]extraData:("xxx=xxxx;bbbb=bbbb;client=xxxx;Account=oooo;ffaijo=efaie";"xxx=xxxx;bbbb=bbbb;Account=oooo;ffaijo=efaie"))
q)update {if[not x like "*client*";:x];";"sv @[s;where (s:";"vs x) like "client=*";:;enlist""]}each extraData from tab

extraData
-----------------------------------------------
"xxx=xxxx;bbbb=bbbb;;Account=oooo;ffaijo=efaie"
"xxx=xxxx;bbbb=bbbb;Account=oooo;ffaijo=efaie"
```

Comment: so i did this                                                             update {if[not x like "*client*" ;:x];";"sv @[s;where (s:";"vs x) like "client=*";:;enlist""]}each extraData from (update {if[not x like "*Account*" ;:x];";"sv @[s;where (s:";"vs x) like "Account=*";:;enlist""]}each extraData from tab)

Answer (score 0):

THIS

```
update {";"sv s@(til count s)except where(s:";"vs x)like\:"client=*"}'[extraData]from a
```